# MySQL syntax error on using if condition in WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-error-1064

I am getting syntax error when I am using `if` conditions in the `WHERE` clause of my Mysql query. For example, if I put in `WHERE 1` with only the condition like `sector = 2`, it is working. But when I put the `if` conditions, it is not working anymore.

```
$query= "SELECT 
   P.id
  ,P.price
  ,P.contract
  ,P.property_type
  ,P.sector
  ,P.title
  ,P.address
  ,P.bedrooms
  ,P.bathrooms
  ,P.price
  ,P.m2
  ,P.text_english
  ,P.photo_01
  ,P.utilities
  ,P.google_maps
  ,P.date


  ,CT.id
  ,CT.english_text
  ,PT.id
  ,PT.english
  ,C.cityname
  ,S.sectorname
  ,S.id
  ,O.ownername
  ,O.phone_one
  ,O.phone_two
  ,O.email
  ,O.notes

FROM properties P
JOIN contract CT
  ON CT.id = P.contract
JOIN property_type PT
  ON PT.id = P.property_type
JOIN city C
  ON C.id = P.city
JOIN sector S
  ON S.id = P.sector
JOIN owner O
  ON O.id = P.owner WHERE 1";           
            if (!empty($sector)) { $query .= "AND P.sector = '$sector'"; }
            if (!empty($property_type))  { $query .= " AND P.property_type = '$property_type'"; }
            if (!empty($contract))  { $query .= " AND P.contract = '$contract'"; }
            if (!empty($minimum_price))  { $query .= " AND P.price BETWEEN '$minimum_price' AND '$maximum_price'"; }
            if (!empty($m2_from))  { $query .= " AND P.m2 BETWEEN '$m2_from' AND '$m2_until'"; }
            if (!empty($bedrooms))  { $query .= " AND P.bedrooms = '$bedrooms'"; }
```

**This is the error:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'P.sector = 2
>   LIMIT 0, 30' at line 43' in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\dolche\admin\class\pagination.php:451 Stack trace: #0
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\dolche\admin\class\pagination.php(451):
>   PDOStatement->execute() #1
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\dolche\admin\search.php(190): pagination->execute() #2
>   {main} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\dolche\admin\class\pagination.php on
>   line 451

Any help resolving this issue will be very welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a space between `1` and `AND`:

```
if (!empty($sector)) { $query .= "AND P.sector = '$sector'"; }
                                ^^^^
                                HERE
```

Interestingly enough, you got it right everywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a space before your `AND`.

Try:

```
if (!empty($sector)) { $query .= " AND P.sector = '$sector'"; }
```

instead of

```
if (!empty($sector)) { $query .= "AND P.sector = '$sector'"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Space before `AND P.sector = '$sector'`

Change from

```
if (!empty($sector)) { $query .= "AND P.sector = '$sector'"; }
```

To

```
if (!empty($sector)) { $query .= " AND P.sector = '$sector'"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give space either:

```
ON O.id = P.owner WHERE 1 ";
```

or

```
if (!empty($sector)) { $query .= " AND P.sector = '$sector'"; }
```